# How to redirect to custom error page with rewritten urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I rewrote my url to become clean urls. The main format is this:

```
profile.php?user_id=$id&section=discussions
```

and rewritten format is this:

```
profile/$id/discussions
```

so what i want to do is redirect the user to a *`page_not_found.php`* if the user types an `$id` of a user that does not exist so i want to redirect them to :
page_not_found.php instead it is redirecting them to

```
profile/$id/page_not_found.php
```

I need your help please on how to do that ?

```
redirect_to("profile/".$user_id_from_link."/discussions"); // redirect_to is a custom function which i made in function.php to redirect faster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, you can do this by checking ID. Before redirect.

Steps:

1. The first check ID value which you get from URL is valid or not.

Let's see how you check. Write a SQL query for check provided Id (Ex.99,90) user exists or not .

Small code for example:

```
$userCheckExists =   select * from 'table-name' where 'colmn-name' == $user_id_from_link

if($userCheckExists) {
    redirect_to("profile/".$user_id_from_link."/discussions"); 
} else {
    redirect_to("./page_not_found.php"); 
}
```

Comment: no not my question, i know how to check the problem i am having is the redirect_to("page_not_found.php"), it is redirecting to profile/$id/page_not_found.php but instead it should be page_not_found.php without the profile/$id/

Comment: Oh.I am extreamly sorry jwright91. You can check using this one .redirect_to("/page_not_found.php");  I hope this will works. Pls let me know.It works or not. or redirect_to("domain/directory_of_your_file_Location/page_not_found.php");

Comment: thanks it worked ! can you please put as a solution?